Weird effect appear when I'm close to a windows
I don't understand why this happened
it happen when I move the camera near the glass
Only happen when I move the camera from the up to down, if I move it down to up, this effect do not happen
I’m not using any reflection probes or light groups





I'm using unity 6 and HDRP (high definition render pipeline)

it was the camera the background type was set to none it should be sky
